# Paste the Files present in any folder into Richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am having multiple format files(.jpeg,.txt,.doc,.excel) in a folder.I want to show those file with their icon in richtextbox in c#.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pp);
foreach (string file in files)
{ 
     StringCollection paths = new StringCollection(); 
     paths.Add(file); // Clipboard.
     // Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
     // lst.Items.Add(file); 
     rht_attachment.Focus(); 
     Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
      rht_attachment.Paste(); 
 }
```

Comment: What have u tried so far???

Comment: string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pp);


                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {

                        StringCollection paths = new StringCollection();
                        paths.Add(file);
                       // Clipboard.
                        // Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
                        // lst.Items.Add(file);
                         rht_attachment.Focus();
                         Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
                        rht_attachment.Paste();
                       
                    }

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
richTextBox1.Lines = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, 
                               "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                              .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                              .ToArray();
```

You may wish to use `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` instead for just the current directory

Comment: Note: This doesn't display the icon... (only just seen this)

Comment: This will provide me path of all the files listed in that folder But I want those file in richtext box as they are present in that Folder

Comment: I am having path...   string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pp);

Comment: @user2768577 - I've updated to include only the file name, this still doesn't include the icon though, not sure about that bit yet.. **Edit** [This may help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R)

Comment: string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pp);
DataObject objData = new DataObject();
foreach (string file in files)
{  
 
Clipboard.Clear();
objData.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true, file);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(objData, true);
                            lst.Items.Add(file);
                            rht_attachment.Focus();
                       
                            rht_attachment.Paste();
                            rht_attachment.Update();
                        }
                        rht_attachment.Refresh();

Comment: I am having file object in clipboard but when but when I am pasting it on richtextbox nothing is visible.